# syntax error - php - echo image (name and extension)

Tags: php, image, syntax, echo

I have 2 variables - $imgs which holds the name of an image, and $ex which is the image extension.

I am trying to echo the image.

I am facing a syntax error.

```
  echo '<div align = "center"><img src ="'.$imgs.'"."'.$ex" /></div>';
```

Comment: Even though this isn't a direct answer, take a look at [sprintf](http://ch2.php.net/sprintf). You could end up with `echo sprintf('<div align="center"><img src="%s.%s"/></div>', $imgs, $ex);` which (to me) is a lot cleaner.

Comment: @betadevil Or directly use `printf` (instead of `echo sprintf`), but a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<div align = "center"><img src ="'.$imgs.'"."'.$ex.'" /></div>';
```

You weren't closing your `'` properly or using `.` in the echo when concatenating. Make sure you use a proper syntax highlighting tool, such as Sublime Text or Notepad++. This makes spotting errors like this much easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
"'.$imgs.'"."'.$ex"
```

needs to be

```
"'.$imgs.'.'.$ex.'"
```

You must properly concatenate the variable here, also you added `"` around the `.` which would have resulted in `foo"."jpg` for example. You should have been able to see this from the syntax highlighting (of SO or your editor).

Answer (score 0):

You're messing the " ' with the .
First of all:Try to write with some style!
For example every time when I have to concatenate something I`m using the empty space for more clear view.

```
'<div align = "center"><img src ="' . $imgs . '.' . $ex . '"/></div>';
```

That way it`s really more clear where ' or " starts and ends.